# How to make date comparison in yii framework

Tags: date, yii, comparison

I am creating project in yii. I am having Poll table with the fields as-
-pollId
-pollQustion
-isActive
-publishDate

I want to check weather publishdate of poll is not greater than current date.
I am implementing as-

```
$CurrrentDate=new CDbExpression('NOW()');
if($record->publishDate < $CurrrentDate))
{
  some code......
}
```

But its not executing correctly. Code is executing even if publish date is greater than current date. So how to make this comparison in yii framework. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP do not have a date format. When you compare $CurrentDate and $record->publishDate you compare strings. Well, for right compare you need to convert it to Unix's timestamp

```
// here you set right date/time pattern 
// You need to explain CDateTimeParser for your pattern
// just easy use `strtotime` if you have 2012-12-12 12:12:12
$publishTimestamp = strtotime($record->publishDate);
// $publishTimestamp = CDateTimeParser::parse($record->publishDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'); 
// if you need to use Hours and minutes just easy use `time()`
$currentDateTimestamp = time();
// $currentDateTimestamp = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
// now we can compare
if ($publishTimestamp  < $currentDateTimestamp) {
   // do some 
}
```

Comment: Thanx sir for reply.. My publishDate is getting stored in format of- "2012-12-13 05:50:05" So what changes i need to do to set this pattern?

Comment: Thanx sir....its also working...Above method does not require to enter current date maually..Thanx sir...